# Как отследить старую версию Safari в JS?

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, webbrowser, safari

Подскажите, как отследить, что пользователь зашел на сайт с мобильного Сафари (iPhone 4-5 и ниже) *Насколько мне известно там Safari v5-7 и она больше не будет обновляться. Так же буду благодарен если кто-то подскажет, бесплатные сайты для тестирование данной версии кроме [live.browserstack.com](http://live.browserstack.com)

Comment: Хак https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/8033179